# Create a mapping between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapping

I have two queries returning the following data:

Result 1:

```
2017-02-27 10:54:30.000
2017-02-27 10:55:30.000
2017-02-27 10:59:30.000
2017-02-27 11:02:30.000
```

Result 2:

```
2017-02-27 10:52:42.000    2017-02-27 10:55:00.000
2017-02-27 10:55:05.000    2017-02-27 10:55:43.000
2017-02-27 10:57:30.000    2017-02-27 11:00:12.000
2017-02-27 11:01:55.000    2017-02-27 11:02:57.000
```

Think of the rows in the second result set as time intervals and let's call the first column 'start' and the second column 'end'. What I need is to create some kind of mapping and find out how many rows from the second result set does not have a 'match' in the first set. What I mean by that...

Here is an example: Look at the first row R1 of the second table.

```
2017-02-27 10:52:42.000    2017-02-27 10:55:00.000
```

If there is no row in the first table so that its value would be between the start and end values then we would return row R1. The output should be the count of all such rows.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

One approach here is to left join the table containing the intervals to the first table.  Then count all records from the second table for which no timestamp from the first table falls in between an interval.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Result2 r2
LEFT JOIN Result1 r1
    ON r1.dt BETWEEN r2.interval1 AND r2.interval2
WHERE r1.dt IS NULL
```

Comment: If you compare your answer to the one below, is there any performance difference? Thanks!

Comment: Tough call...the other answer might be slightly faster, but both should be pretty fast if you have indices on the interval columns.

Comment: How would this change if I wanted it so that the rows from r1 can be used only once? In other words don't map one timestamp to two intervals. Thanks!

Comment: You would need to provide additional logic for this, and probably update your tsbles as well.

Answer (score 1):

> If there is no row in the first table so that its value would be between the start and end values

This can be translated pretty directly into SQL:

```
select count(*) from Result2 r2
where not exists (
    select * from Result1 r1
    where r1.value between r2.start and r2.end
)
```

Comment: If you compare your answer to the one above, is there any performance difference? Thanks!

Comment: I can't really say - the SQL optimizer is pretty smart. Best way to find out is by testing! Try running both versions on real data, and turn on "Include actual execution plan" to see what they're doing

Comment: How would this change if I wanted it so that the rows from r1 can be used only once? In other words don't map one timestamp to two intervals. Thanks!

Comment: That actually sounds a lot more complicated.. I think you should ask a new question about it. Also, how do you determine which interval gets the timestamp if more than one could use it?

Comment: True. I am hoping that my data doesn't allow for overlaps (or at least not frequently), so I will probably won't worry about it for now. Thanks! :]